# Hive query on HUE shows different timestamp than programatically/on data

Tags: hive, timestamp, timezone, parquet, hue

I have an external columnar (GZip-compressed Parquet files on an S3 bucket) Hive (2.1.1) table with a `timestamp` column.

Visualizing the parquet file with ParquetViewer, I get the following record (censored a column due to sensitive data):

[image: Censored for sensitive data]

If I were to SELECT for this specific record in HUE, I get the following result instead:

```
SELECT end_dt_ym, pod, end_dt_d, bill_ordr, period_start FROM <table> WHERE pod='<sensitive data>' AND end_dt_ym='202202'
```

[image]

It is one hour after the actual parquet-stored data.

What could be causing this issue? How would I fix this?
I appreciate any help.

I've tried casting to `string` using `date_format()`, but still no dice.

I also tried to mess around with timezones but apparently Hive already defaults to UTC anyway.

Comment: Can you try setting this property in your hive session and see if anything changes SET hive.session.time.zone=UTC;